# Trying to install composer on goormide

Tags: composer-php

I am trying to install composer to GoormIDE. Before this I used to use cloud9 which was pretty simple but now I need to move on any other cloud services so I found GoormIDE. I wasn't able to install the composer.

I tried a couple of links but I keep on getting errors like `bash: composer: command not found`

links I tried
`https://getcomposer.org/download/
https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md
https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-composer`

I want to install composer and then laravel so that I can start coding. I am using PHP 7.1 in GoormIDE.

Comment: that goormide https://ide.goorm.io/my?plan=ZnJlZQ==

Answer (score 1):

You probably could see that `composer.phar` file is generated after you followed instructions at https://getcomposer.org/download/ .

You need to make this `composer.phar` file accessible globally, to use `composer` command anywhere on your system.
Type this command to make it global:
`mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

BTW, [goormIDE](https://ide.goorm.io/) is currently providing Ubuntu 14.04 for PHP stack, and PHP is no longer supporting that version of Ubuntu.
So if you're going to set laravel environment with further progress, I recommand you to create a new container with Blank(Ubuntu 16.04) stack and install PHP in the container. You can install PHP with just one click at `Install PHP 7.3` option at `Additional module/package` step.

#### In conclusion:

1. Click `Create a new container` at [goormIDE](https://ide.goorm.io/) dashboard.
2. Input a name of container.
3. At `Choose a software stack` step, choose `Blank (16.04)`.
4. At `Additional module/package` step, choose `Install PHP 7.3` option.
5. Create and open the container.
6. Type following commands on your terminal.

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '48e3236262b34d30969dca3c37281b3b4bbe3221bda826ac6a9a62d6444cdb0dcd0615698a5cbe587c3f0fe57a54d8f5') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

7. Type `composer --help` to confirm your installation.